# How to specify a range of solidity versions?

Tags: solidity, version-pragma

How would I specify in the `pragma solidity` a range of acceptable solidity versions. If I want to specify that it should be gte(greater than equal) for example I could use `pragma solidity >=0.8.0`, and so on for the other in/equalities. But how do I specify a range for example from `0.8.0` to `0.8.10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer it's simply as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <=0.8.10;
```

Comment: upvoted answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <=0.8.10;
```

Comment: Hmm, I managed to find the answer and it's identical to yours :)

Comment: @MShakeG You posted a few seconds before this answer. So technically, your own answer should be the one to select ^^

Comment: @MShakeG the most important thing is that you figured out the solution. It doesn't matter who provided the answer